# Upload com drag and drop?

Tags: javascript, html5

Esse campo de upload arrastando o arquivo é feito com drag and drog do HTML5? 
Tem que ativar alguma coisa com JS?
Pelo que vi em outros sites esse campo deve funcionar como o botão de upload também.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tem vários plugins gratuítos que você pode utilizar, sugiro esse aqui. https://github.com/devbridge/html5-file-uploader https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/drag-and-drop-uploader/

Comment: Talvez o  @Marcelo Bonifazio possa te ajudar

Comment: Obrigada, vou dar uma olhada (:

Comment: Eu te passei uma resposta com uns links de plugins, mas como acharam que não era útil então espera alguém vim te ajudar.